# Flash plugin failed to load - jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, jsfiddle, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I have normal jwplayer set up here in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/nL9tazxo/12/).

```
Link : https://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/nL9tazxo/12/
```

but it is throwing the error in video player screen.

Please help me debug this issue

Comment: I have the same issue, any news about it?

Comment: where are you getting this issue @ohadsas

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the flash plugin not supported error is happening, but I changed the primary player mode to explicitly be html5, which solves the issue here for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/simsketch/nL9tazxo/14/

```
jwplayer("player-widget-container").setup({
    file: "http://182.70.125.99/edge360/videos/cam1/fast.mp4",
    title: "title",
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    primary: 'html5'
  });
```

Hope this helps!

Note: On jsfiddle, you don't need to include jquery or the doc ready wrapper as you had done in your example.